# Why doesn't write() work properly?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    int in = STDIN_FILENO;
    int out = STDOUT_FILENO;
    char word[100];
    int count;

    while ((count = read(in, word, 100)) != 0) {
        write(out, word, strlen(word));
        memset(word, 0, 255);
        count = read(in, word, 5);
    }
}
```

In the console I got

```
hello world
hello world
hello stackoverflow
 stackoverflow
abcd
efgh
efgh
```

Why isn't this program echoing back exactly as it was written?

Comment: `memset(word, 0, 255);`, but `char word[100];`???

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`memset(word, 0, 255);` is causing undefined behavior. You are accessing index out of bounds for word. Also please note that as you are using `strlen` on word, you should always zero terminate as read does not do that.

Comment: memset() beyond the buffer is, as you state, undefined. The more direct problem is the second read as identified by timrau that swallows subsequent leading 5-character strings.

This question seems like a troll.

Answer (score 1):

You called `count = read(in, word, 5);` in the end of the `while` loop. That 5 bytes are dropped. That's why the `"hello"` in `"hello stackoverflow"` and the `"abcd\n"` in `"abcd\nefgh"` are dropped.